# Knex migration fails with - SAVEPOINT can only be used in transaction blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to create a knex migration. The migration should be a transaction that should add role and some users to database. If the users are already in db the transaction should change their role_id to new role_id

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  async function transaction(t) {

    await t.raw('INSERT INTO "public"."role" VALUES (3, \'external_support\');');

    let i;

    for(i = 0; i < newUsers.length; i += 1) {

      const result = await t.raw('SELECT id FROM "public"."user" WHERE email = ?;', [
        newUsers[i].email
      ]);

      if (result.rowCount === 0) {
        await t.raw('INSERT INTO "public"."user" (email, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?);', [
          newUsers[i].email,
          newUsers[i].firstname,
          newUsers[i].lastname
        ]);
        await t.raw('INSERT INTO "public"."users_roles" VALUES ((SELECT id FROM "public"."user" WHERE email = ?) , 3);', [
          newUsers[i].email
        ]);
      } else {
         await t.raw('UPDATE "public"."users_roles" SET role_id = 3 WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM "public"."user" WHERE email = ?);', [
          newUsers[i].email
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
```

So basic logic behind this is (should be) 
  - add new role
  - check whether users exist
    - If not add users and set their role_id to new
    - If yes then change their role_id to new

So, what I get is

```
`error: SAVEPOINT can only be used in transaction blocks`
```

Why?

Comment: Knex creates implicitly transaction for your migration, so that might have something to do with savepoint error (nested transactions are savepoints). Other thing is that your code doesn't make sense. You are just creating an async function inside module.export.up and then not even calling it. So basically you are running an empty migration.

Comment: no no there is   `return knex.transaction(transaction);` but i did not write it here. `module.export.up` is called when I type `knex migrate:latest`

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to have correct code? But maybe your code throws an error before calling that transaction, which may cause implicit rollback in transaction, then knex doesn't notice that transaction was broken and tries to create savepoint for creating inner transaction. Impossible to know without seeing actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that I did not pay attention to [documentation](https://knexjs.org/). I know I had seen this but I totally forgot.

```
By default, each migration is run inside a transaction.
```

So creating the transaction in transaction will lead to fussy behavior. In this case that was double committing.